# How to avoid override of a list element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If you run the code snippet below you can observe the following:
at first `console.log()` it print 0,Jhon after I modified the first element of the first array the same change is also reversed on the object in the second list, why?
its possible to avoid this?

This is a sample of this problem:

```js
var myArray = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Jhon"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Sara"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Domnic"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Bravo"
  }
];
var a = [];
a.push(myArray[0]);
console.log(a);
myArray[0].name = 'TEST';
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Because they're two references to the same mutable object. If that's not the behaviour you want, push a *copy* into a.

Comment: can you provide a sample of what you mean ?

Comment: See [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: This one has a [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/11719787) Read this

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks , finally it work , the clone function is very useful

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want it to be by reference, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
a.push({...myArray[0]});
```

complete code:

```js
var myArray = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Jhon"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Sara"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Domnic"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Bravo"
  }
];
var a = [];
a.push({...myArray[0]});
console.log(a);
myArray[0].name = 'TEST';
console.log(a);
```